# Dynamics CRM - JS ReferenceError "X" is not defined

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I have a short bit of Javascript that sets fields to optional for certain forms.

I've checked syntax multiple times, checked the execute order in the CRM Form, and there are no references to other JS Libraries.

```
function getFormName() {
       var formName;
       formName = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem().getLabel();

        if (formName == "EPS Plan Form") {
              Xrm.Page.getAttribute("abc_plan_type").setRequiredLevel("none");
              Xrm.Page.getAttribute("usi_erisa_plan").setRequiredLevel("none");
              Xrm.Page.getAttribute("abc_product").setRequiredLevel("none");
        }
}
```

The error I'm getting seems to be in reference to general syntax issues :

```
ReferenceError: getName is not defined 
at eval (eval at RunHandlerInternal 
    at RunHandlerInternal 
    at RunHandlers 
    at OnScriptTagLoaded
```

Comment: You are missing some code, as you are not using `getName` in the provided code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your event trigger on the form might be configured to call a function called `getName`...

If you check the form Properties > Events, do you see a call to `getName` in the OnLoad event? Based on your function name above you'd need it to call `getFormName`.

And for the record, [Xrm.Page is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/important-changes-coming#some-client-apis-are-deprecated) in favor of passing execution context and using `executionContext.getFormContext()` (except when referencing the parent page from a web resource, in which case Xrm.Page is still supported, last I heard.)

[image: form properties]